# Xcode6.1 Swift If error

Tags: if-statement, swift, xcode6.1

I am making a To do list app and well I need to create a delete button so when the self (user) swipes the task to the left a red button will say delete.

So well I started to create the code imported from `UITableViewDataSource` and well the code I am trying to use is `if(editingStyle) == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)` and well when I put it into the code, the code throws back a error saying (!) Expected '{' after 'if' condition.

So is there anyway to get round this because I have tried to but a { after if but loads more errors come back!

[image]

Comment: you have 2 ')' in that same IF statement, it should just be "if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) { //Code }" 

Also would like to point out... that in your code, unless you are doing it in the Xib file, you have not set the Delegate and the Datasource of the UITableView in your class 'FirstViewController'.

Comment: Please do *not* post code as images. This will prevent people using screen-readers from helping you, as well as make copying the code into a playground for testing / copying and modifying it inside an answer impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace those 3 lines with these 4. You have a parenthesis error and a bracket error.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
    taskMgr.tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}
tblTasks.reloadData()
```

Also, make sure that you've properly set your UITableView dataSource and delegate. You can do this in IB or you can do this by replacing your existing viewDidLoad with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblTasks.delegate = self
    tblTasks.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: and also i am getting UITableViewDataSource error in my 'class FirstViewController:'

Comment: Have you set your datasource and delegate? If you haven't set these properly in IB, then set them in your code. I've updated my answer.